# Versioning JSON data in db

Tags: json, versioning, sqlite

I'm curious if there are any obvious pitfalls to the following:

I have a database table that, because it is storing many objects of various subclasses, I'm using a JSON field to hold the non-overlapping properties. (i.e., the common properties like id, creation_date, parent_id, type are all separate "normal" fields, and the rest gets stored in a JSON column).

I would like to eventually track changes to these objects, and the traditional methods (pre-JSON columns) seem less than ideal, especially the ones that have a unique row for each property change. I'm thinking the more efficient solution is to have a history table that just has three columns: FK, modification_date, and a JSON structure that contains all of the changed/added fields. (I imagine the JSON data won't be nested too deeply, so the update/added fields would simply overwrite at the parent level.)

I had also thought about storing the revisions inside the main table and having the revision point to the parent and a boolean flag for is_revision. Which then might allow for queries on a single table, and for other objects to be able to point their parent_id to a specific revision.

Am I missing a more obvious solution?

Comment: As a rule of thumb in IT - if you don't have detailed and solid reasons, don't reinvent the bycicle or use non-standard approaches. Common tables and versioning schemas will do all things you'd described here. It's impossible to give a better answer. 1. What exactly (less than ideal isn't a good description) do you trying to achieve abandoning the standard scheme? 2. What tech stack do you use (Postgres, for example, can treat JSON(b) as it's still structured data with fields, indexes, etc.)? 3. What are the requirements for the versioning system (diffs, size or search speed efficiency, etc.)?

Comment: Good point on not reinventing the wheel. Obviously the common versioning technique was standardized long before JSON became a field option, and I suspect I'm not finding any updated techniques, because the option is still fairly new. 2. Sqlite, which handles JSON. 3. My only (future) requirement for versioning is that it work with as few brittle parts as possible. I don't know yet how exactly it'll all fit together.

Comment: 1. If SqLite really all the related stack - all drawbacks will be specific to its JSON handling. If it handles JSON content along with other fields seamless - there will be no difference for end-user. I have no experience with it - you could ask it as a separate question to get answers from SqLite with JSON users.

Comment: 2. "few brittle parts as possible" - It's still an awful requirement, either versioning can pass or fail on it. It sounds like you should just take ready solutions and figure out will they work for you or not. For example - will the simplest content agnostic versioning way do it https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/versioning-workflows.html ? If no - move to checking more complex variants, etc.